# Android - Arranging Buttons at Foot of Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

An app I am working on needs to have two buttons anchored to the bottom of the screen. The technique I've used in the past is to declare a RelativeLayout for the buttons within a parent RelativeLayout (height = fill_parent) and set align_parent_bottom to true. This is declared first and has an id so the next child layout can declare itself to be above the buttons' RelativeLayout.

However, the screen I'm currently working on has a strange problem - there is a large empty gap before the first View object appears:
[image]

[Here is my layout XML](http://www.pastie.org/3988929)

Can anyone spot where my problem is? Is there a better way to arrange my buttons?

Comment: Please post code in http://www.pastie.org.. Here pastebin is blocked

Comment: @Venky Done - please see new link.

Comment: I guess there is no more content below the TextField "My description", right? Then the solution for your question is, that the buttons align to the bottom of the view, the ScrollView is above the buttons, and as it doesn't need all the available space (wrap-content), it aligns itself to the bottom and leaves a blank area at the top. If you align your ScrollView to the top, make it fillParent and align the button-RelativeLayout to be below the ScrollView, it should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code , It will work .

Problem is `android:layout_above="@id/alarm_details_buttons_layout"`
in Scroll View

[Edited Code](http://www.pastie.org/private/faukcdwleux5jib1u4pa)

Comment: It does work, but I'm not quite sure how. In your code there is no relationship between the button RelativeLayout and the ScrollView, yet the ScrollView does not overlap the buttons. I would have thought the ScrollView would obscure the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and here is the `modification in your buttons layout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/alarm_details_buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alarm_details_return_to_list_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="your text here"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alarm_details_update_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm_details_return_to_list_button"
            android:state_enabled="false"
            android:text="your text here"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi. What is the modification? I can only see that the button width size has gone and the RelativeLayout width is now wrap_content. Not sure how this is either a better way of positioning the buttons or getting rid of the gap at the top of the screen. I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: Needed what for? The problem is that there was a empty space at the top of the screen. It's fixed now - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

fixed. http://pastebin.com/ucHwzJQP

Note i removed all "@string/", will need to be added back.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not quite what I was after - the biutton are now not at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Im not sure what you want then lol, you do or dont want the buttons at the bottom? If you want to move the buttons up from the bottom all you need to do is change "0dp" to "wrap_content" on the scrollview, but that would make the scrollview pointless.

Comment: I do want the buttons at the bottom which they were originally. The problem was a big empty space at the top of the screen, so I was concerned that the way I was positioning my buttons had something to do with it. See my answer for the fix. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the 'gap' problem. As I have set the scroll view to be positioned above the buttons RelativeLayout, I also had to force it to align with it's parent's top:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/alarm_details_buttons_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```